# How can I break a 'while' loop while I'm in a switch-case in C#?

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, break

I want to break this `while` loop if `n` equals 3 but how can I do?

```
n = 0;
while(true){
    switch (n){
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the few places a `goto` is legit

Answer (score 5):

You can't break out of a nested block. You must use a different conditional control structure.

For example, you can use a boolean in the while loop:

```
while(true) {
  var breakWhile = false;
  switch(n) {
    case 3:
      breakWhile = true;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  if (breakWhile) {
    break;
  }
}
```

This is a fairly contrived example to show how you would do it in a general sense.

In this simple example you can simplify the code to just:

```
while (n != 3) {

}
```

But I figured you're interested in a general approach to breaking out of nested structures.

Another, frowned upon practice, would be to use a [goto statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto). You should generally avoid this but showing here for sake of completeness and because incidentally, getting out of deeply nested loops is one of the few acceptable uses of the `goto` statement.

From docs:

> The goto statement is also useful to get out of deeply nested loops.

```
while (true) {
  switch(n) {
    case 3:
      goto outer_scope;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
outer_scope:
  // ...
```

Comment: Or perhaps just `while (!breakWhile)` ? (after moving its declaration out of the loop, of course)

Comment: or that.. I was trying to keep as close to the original structure since I figured the OP is looking for a general approach to breaking out of nested loops, or scopes

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a do ... while, instead of a while ... do.

```
var n = 0;
do {
    switch (n)
    {
        case 3:
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
} while(n != 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool run = true;
n = 0;
while(run){
    switch (n){
        case 3:
            run = false
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

or you can use n

n = 0;
while(n!=3){    }